# How to open password protected db in sqlite3 using c++?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I m trying to open password protected db using sqlite3 in c++ means programmatically.
`sqlite3 *m_sqlite;    int ret = sqlite3_open("test.db", &m_sqlite);`
But its for open a normal db , there is any other function to open password  protected db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sqlite3_user_authenticate` to open db which requires authentication.

The syntax goes as below.

```
int sqlite3_user_authenticate(
     sqlite3 *db,           /* The database connection */
     const char *zUsername, /* Username */
     const char *aPW,       /* Password or credentials */
     int nPW                /* Number of bytes in aPW[] */
   );
```

Call sequence goes as below.

```
int ret = sqlite3_open("test.db", &m_sqlite);
ret = sqlite3_user_authenticate(m_sqlite,"username","password",8);
```

For more info refer https://www.sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/ext/userauth/user-auth.txt sqlite doc.

Comment: i m working on win32c++ nd using #include"sqlite3.h" header file , when i m going to use this function it shows me error that "sqlite3_user_authenticate" is undefined??Can you pls help to get right header file for it.

Comment: Activate the user authentication logic by including the
ext/userauth/userauth.c source code file in the build and
adding the -DSQLITE_USER_AUTHENTICATION compile-time option.
The ext/userauth/sqlite3userauth.h header file is available to
applications to define the interface.

Comment: read `user-auth.txt` in https://www.sqlite.org/src/dir?ci=24b0f66ac611e26f&name=ext/userauth